# abnormal bandwidth between ec2 instance for mysql replication

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using MySQL replication between 2 AWS Instance: m4.xlarge.
Version 5.6.35

Sometimes I have trouble with replication lag time is high, increased too much up to seconds_behind_master xx,000 seconds. I found that io_thread on slave can not catch up bin_logs size on master db.

At this time, the bandwidth & byte transmit between master & slave is very low (count in bytes)

But when I changed the instance type of Slave from m4.xlarge to t2.xlarge and backward. The bandwidth between master slave increased immediately ( up to 400kb/s). Keep master db, no touch or change on it. ANd soon the replication lag disappear. This is weird.
(iftop to check bandwidth)

Could you please advise what is wrong with this? what happend when we change the instance type? and How can we detect the root cause?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Note: Before the lag time become high, there alots of commit/update on master db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked & monitored that the problem come from our Slave DB running out of `Burst Balance`. (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-burst-balance-metric-for-ec2s-general-purpose-ssd-gp2-volumes/).

As our slave DB has small storage just 20GB so it just has default 100 IOPS.

```
IOPS = Volume size (in GB) * 3
Minimum for gp2 is 100 IOPS
Maximum for gp2 is 3000 IOPS
```

I increased the storage to 50GB to get 150 IOPS and now io_thread running better.

Stop/start instance also reset Burst Balance to 100% but it is a quick tip only. This metric should be checked beside bandwidth incase high latency between EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are some one ran into the same problem [[1]](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=548272) [[2]](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151729)

Did you try to turn off sync_binlog ? ( sync_binlog=0 )

Comment: Yes, the sync_binlog has been turned off.  This variable was setup from the beginning of replication 6 months ago.


| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| sync_binlog   | 0     |

Comment: Seems like a case to contact aws support for me. Did you try  to replicate the issue with another mySql version?

Comment: Thanks. Not yet, just use my current version 5.6.35. By the way is it possible to setup replication between Master 5.6.35 and slave with higher version?

Comment: I have tested again, that the action stop + start EC2 instance work on this case. (it is not about changing instance type). It is also not work with rebooting. It's weird, that stop & start Ec2 instance will change the physical machine behind ec2-instance? Am i right?

Comment: Yes, most of the time.
It also release the EIP associated to the instance

Comment: Finally, I have checked & monitored that the problem come from our Slave DB running out of Burst Balance. (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-burst-balance-metric-for-ec2s-general-purpose-ssd-gp2-volumes/). As our slave DB has small storage just 20GB so it just has 100 IOPS. I increased the storage to 50GB to get 150 IOPS and now io_thread running better. Stop/start instance also reset Burst Balance to 100%. This metric should be checked beside bandwidth incase high latency between EC2 instances. Thanks so much for your help. @qkhanhpro.

Comment: That's interesting to know. You should create an answer and mark that so that It can help other people @KhoaTran

Comment: Well noted. Thanks so much @qkhanhpro